# Add another div to script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a popup on my website but don't know how to add an extra `#youtube-popup` div to the below script.

```
function div_show() {
  document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "block";
}

function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle(function() {
e.removeClass('selected');
  });
}

$(function() {
  $('#youtube').on('click', function() {
if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
  deselect($(this));
} else {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.pop').slideFadeToggle();
}
return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
deselect($('#youtube'));
return false;
  });
});

$.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(easing, callback) {
  return this.animate({
opacity: 'toggle'
  }, 'fast', easing, callback);
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Also, if you know how to remove the fade animation, please let me know.

Comment: Could you add some HTML please? Or perhaps a fiddle

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind event to multiple elements use basic css selector `selector1, selector2`.

To remove fade animation simply change function from `slideFadeToggle` to `slideToggle`.

Here is stripped and fixed code to apply for multiple elements:

```
function deselect(e) {
  $('.pop').slideToggle('normal', function() {
    e.removeClass('selected');
  });
}

$(function() {
  $('#youtube, #youtube-popup').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      deselect($(this));
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('.pop').slideToggle();
    }

    return false;
  });

  $('.close').on('click', function() {
    deselect($(this).closest('#youtube, #youtube-popup')); // I assume .close is inside popup and you want only paret to be closed.

    return false;
  });
});
```